# i want to print addition of two numbers. example " Vishal has 20+30 rupees."

Tags: string, c#-4.0

I have statement which has 2 integer numbers , so i want to print addition of that two numbers. example " Vishal has 20 + 30 rupees."            thanks in advance

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Please be more specific with your question and your situation that needs a solution. You tag your question with asp.net-mvc-4 and yet you mentioned nothing about mvc.

Answer (score 2):

```
Console.Write(String.Format("Visual has {0} + {1} rupees", 20, 30));
```